# Outlook API - Get shared event

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365api, outlook-restapi

I use outlook API v2.
I get the list of events from a shared calendar.
I use this API call: `/users('{EMAIL}')/CalendarView`

I would like to be able to get a specific event with its ID.

I can make a call on my own calendar but the call "get events" on an event in a shared calendar does not seem to work.

The call to get a specific event from my own calendar: `/Me/Events/{ID_EVENT}`

Can you help me ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please try /users//events/ to see details of shared event?

Comment: Hi,When i try this i just have a 404 error. i need to add oQuery data. It's works but i need to have a complete shared event. Do you have an idea ?